# Current Flow indicator using LED

Tags: led, current, measurement

I want to build a simple measurement circuit for indicating the load on a little 12V pump. Assuming that the pump draws 200 to 2000mA depending on the load, how can I connect lets say 5 Red LEDs so that they are turned on in  400mA steps.
To be more precise: 
For 0mA no LED is on.
For 400mA one LED is on.
For 800mA two LED are on.
Etc.

The pump is directly connected to the power source.
Is there a way to do this using simple parts (resistors and LEDs)? If not how can it be done?

I want to build the circuit from scratch to get a better understanding of electronics.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this. R9 should be a 1W or 2W resistor. D6 prevents surge current from damaging the resistor. There are 4 op-amps in each LM324 so you would need two of them (or 3 LM358s). The 7805 creates a reference voltage which is divided down to the transition voltages for each LED. 20uA through the divider chain so steps of 40mV, representing 400mA through the load.

Connections to R9 need to be kept low resistance and arranged as shown (split at the bottom end close to the resistor),

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbE6aR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

Edit: added explanation:

The op-amp comparators have outputs that go high (illuminating the respective LED) when the "+" input exceeds the "-" input.

The 6-resistor divider chain starting with R12 and ending with R13 creates the 5 comparison voltages for the five comparators. the nominal voltages are 40mV/80mV/120mV/160mV/200mV.

All the current through the pump goes through the sense resistor R9. That steals a bit of voltage from the pump motor- 200mV at 2A. R11 and C1 form a low pass filter to smooth the pump current sensing a bit, but don't affect the average voltage sensed by R9. So, as the current through the pump increases from 0, the LED D5 illuminates at about 400mA, D4 illuminates at about 800mA and so on up to 2A where D1 illuminates (the lower current LEDs are still illuminated so it's like a thermometer code).

Comment: If you don’t mind wasting power and have enough voltage to play with, old school VU-meters had LED+resistor+Zener with ever increasing Zener value as you go up the ladder. Saves you some comparators.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since I'm pretty new to electronics it would be nice if you could further explain why certain LEDs are switched on depending on the current consumption of the pump.

Comment: See above edit.

Comment: Dear Spehro, that is truly amazing. So If the current of the pump increases, also the voltages at the positive inputs increase and hence the LEDs are lit. But for my understanding, could you please help me by answering the following parts of the circuit:

a) Why do you need to 'steal' voltage from the pump? Is this necessary for the circuit to work? How is the 'stealing' done by using R9?      

b) How does the low pass filter work, or how is this behavior triggered by using R11 and C1 ? I assume it deletes high oscillating frequencies of the current causes by the motor.

Comment: It’s not essential, but it vastly simplifies things to drop a bit of voltage. It’s how most fuses, ammeters and circuit breakers work. Google RC low pass filter for more info on that - the cutoff frequency is about 0.5Hz.

Comment: Why does dopping the voltage simplifies things? I mean, at 12V and 2A the remaining voltage is still 11.8V according to your specs.

Comment: The 0.2V is enough to work with ( the LM324 has an offset voltage of only a few mV so the 40mV steps are reasonably accurate) and 0.2V is less than 2% of the 12V. If you wanted very close to zero voltage drop from the current measurement circuit you would have to use a more complex power circuit  or something like an hall effect current sensor rather than a simple resistor.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time.
Should the diode not be connected parallel to the pump in opposite direction to prevent the surge current?
Further, how does the "stealing" of the current work and how are the 0.2V are created by adding R9?

Comment: Yes, diode not shown. ALL the current through the pump also goes through R9 which drops a bit of voltage (according to Ohm's law). There's also a bit of voltage drop in the connecting wires etc.

Comment: So, D6 is meant to be parallel to the pump and the voltage drop caused by R9 does lead to an remaining voltage of 0.2V at the opAmps?

Comment: D6 is in the correct place. I explained the reason for it. If you want a diode across the pump or across the switch, that’s additional.

Answer (score 1):

There are dozens of ways to do this.

High/Low side current sense IC or discrete parts that can sense to V+ or 0V.

2A Current with 50mV drop amplified to 5V range needs x100 gain

Bar Graph LED indicators exist with these comparators.  (Search)  Or you can DIY with lots of parts.

LED can vary in intensity from 10mcd to 1000 mcd per milliamp x 20mA so this affects if you need full current or not.  Usually not.

There are clever ways to use transistor ladder drivers by cascading 0.6V per step so 5 steps = 3V full scale but depends if you want simple or complex.

[image]

[LM3914](http://www.ti.com/sitesearch/docs/universalsearch.tsp?searchTerm=LM3914#q=LM3914&t=everything&linkId=1)
[image]

[X100 gain Amp](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+12+0.0005+30.13683688681966+27+5+63%0Aw+32+112+32+176+0%0Ag+32+288+32+320+0%0Av+448+272+368+272+0+1+1+0.05347+0.7895+0+0.5%0Av+32+288+32+192+0+0+110+12+0+0+0.5%0Aw+32+112+336+112+3%0Aw+80+288+336+288+2%0At+368+272+336+272+0+1+-11.138564810259114+0.7851386426855478+100%0Aw+336+256+336+112+0%0Ar+32+288+80+288+0+0.024800000000000003%0Ax+38+309+135+312+4+16+1%5Csft%5Csof%5CsAWG24%0Ab+304+160+490+340+0%0Ax+364+182+403+185+4+16+pump%0Ag+448+272+448+304+0%0A403+64+32+192+96+0+4_64_0_4353_20_3.2_0_2_4_3%0Ac+-32+176+-32+288+0+0.00001+11.961888333063522%0Aw+32+176+-32+176+0%0Aw+176+224+240+224+0%0Ar+96+144+176+144+0+99000%0Ar+96+144+64+144+0+1000%0Aw+-32+288+32+288+0%0Ag+64+144+64+160+0%0Ar+80+240+80+288+0+1000%0A403+192+144+272+208+0+16_64_0_4354_20_0.1_0_2_16_3%0Aw+176+144+176+224+0%0Aw+96+240+80+240+0%0Aw+96+144+96+208+2%0Ar+32+176+32+192+0+0.025%0Aa+96+224+176+224+8+12+0+1000000+0.0381467333854753+0.038184880118860766+100000%0A403+112+320+240+384+0+5_64_0_4354_0.15625_0.1_0_2_5_3%0Ax+394+31+532+34+4+16+T.%5CsStewart%5CsXmas%5Cs'19%0A38+2+0+0.001+0.1+Max%5CsVoltage%0A38+2+2+0+1+DC%5CsOffset%0A) on 25 mOhm current sensor to get 5V from 2A from 50mV 
[image]drop.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Right now I'll try to go with the answer provided by Spehro Pefhany.

Comment: sure Quad OA's are more common but depends on how many bars you need vs simplicity